# Writing a % to a file

Tags: macros, write

I'm writing a macro to write some commands into a text file. This text file is supposed to be read later to execute some macros.

The macro :

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}%
\newwrite\tmpfile%
\immediate\openout\tmpfile=output.tex%
\immediate\write\tmpfile{some text and a percent sign}%
\immediate\closeout\tmpfile%
\end{document}%
```

The exported text

```
some text and a percent sign
```

To avoid boring blanks, I need to finish my lines with a percent sign : **%**

I tried this line

```
\immediate\write\tmpfile{some text and a percent sign\%}%
```

which gave :

```
some text and a percent sign\%
```

and it's not want I want. I would like to have :

```
some text and a percent sign%
```

**Is it possible to write a single percent sign (%) to a file and how to do ?**

Comment: `\@percentchar` usage

Comment: I am not convinced that this is exactly a duplicate as this question is not specifically about `\write18`.  As the system does not let me do otherwise now, I added another answer to that other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `%` is the comment character, you have to change its meaning from catcode 14 to `12`, i.e. a letter. This is done in `latex.ltx` at the definition of `\@percentchar`, however, this introduces another 'awkward' `\makeatletter...\makeatother` usage then, that's why I show the way like `latex.ltx` does it, with `\writepercent` but omitting the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair.

```
\documentclass{article}


\catcode`\%=12
\def\writepercent{%}
\catcode`\%=14


%Also possible

\makeatletter
\def\writepercentother{\@percentchar}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}%


\newwrite\tmpfile%

\immediate\openout\tmpfile=output.tex%
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\tmpfile{some text and a percent sign\@percentchar}
\makeatother
\immediate\write\tmpfile{Another important text and a percent sign\writepercent}
\immediate\closeout\tmpfile%
\end{document}
```